# Imon RM200 remote (device 15c2:ffdc) won't work on Ubuntu 12.04 or 11.10

Tags: 12.04, lirc

The device is recognized just fine:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 15c2:ffdc SoundGraph Inc. iMON PAD Remote Controller

Found /sys/class/rc/rc0/ (/dev/input/event6) with:
    Driver imon, table rc-imon-mce
    Supported protocols: RC-6 
    Enabled protocols: RC-6 
    Repeat delay = 500 ms, repeat period = 125 ms
```

But any testing results in *nothing*.

I point the remote, I press a few button and nothing happens. Not in irw, not in ir-keytable, nothing. It's driving me insane.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same remote. Here is how I got mine to work, at least for testing purposes:

```
ir-keytable -c
ir-keytable -w /lib/udev/rc_keymaps/imon_mce
ir-keytable -t
```

Still need to get it to start automatically at boot, but getting closer...